# Do Sylow subgroups distinguish representations?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, sylow-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, $X$ the set of elementary subgroups of $G$, $Y$ the set of Sylow subgroups of $G$.

Propsition 29 in Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* implies that the set $X$ distinguish representations, in the sense that

> For any finite dimensional complex G-representations $V$ and $W$ whose restrictions to $X_i$ are isomorphic for each element $X_i \in X$, $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

1. I wonder if $Y$ distinguishes representations as well? I have tried some small groups like $A_3, A_4, S_4..$. Note that when $G$ is a compact real Lie group, any maximal torus distinguishes. I'd hope to say Sylow $p$-subgroups (with all possible $p$) should have similar properties, thus asking this question. Thank you.

**EDIT**: Derek has shown by an explicit example that $Y$ is not enough below! Notice also that the elementary subgroups are necessary for $R(G) \to \oplus_{H\in\text{some-set}} R(H)$ to be one-to-one (Green's theorem). For me, this justify why the elementary subgroups are important.

2. How about this: can $Y$ distinguish all **irreducible representations**? This is actually what I had in mind.. but I was not careful enough. If we want to disprove this statement, we have to find two nonisomorphic irreducible representations $V$ and $W$ of $G$ such that their restrictions to any Sylow subgroups are isomorphic.

**EDIT**: A counter example has been found by Derek: $G=D_{2\times 12}$! The faithful irreps of degree $2$ (there are only two of them) restrict to the same ones to the Sylow-$2$ and Sylow-$3$.

Comment: I fail to understand. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: I need to think some more about it, so I have deleted my comment for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $Y$ of Sylow subgroups does not distinguish between complex representations.

Let $G$ be cyclic of order $6$, and consider the two representations $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ of $G$ of degree 2  that map a generator $g$  of $G$ to
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}\omega&0\\0&-\omega^2\end{array}\right)\ \ \ \ \mathrm{and}\ \ \ \ 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\omega&0\\0&\omega^2\end{array}\right),$$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of $1$.

By computing the actions on $g^2$ and $g^3$, you can check that the restirctions of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ to Sylow $3$- and $2$-subgroups of $G$ have the same character and are therefore isomorphic.

For an example with irreducible representations, we can take the two faithful irreducible representations of the dihedral group of order $24$, which are of degree 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I noticed that I forgot to put the condition that $V, W$ should be irreducible. In fact, if we are just proving $R(G) \to \oplus_{H\in Y} R(H)$ is one-to-one, on Serre's book there's a converse theorem roughly saying that $X$ is the best situation we could hope. I have edited the question. But thanks! This is an explicit example showing that the converse theorem is correct -- we do need the set of elementary subgroups to distinguish **all** finite dimensional complex representations.

Comment: The converse statement can be found in Serre's book Chapter 11, Theorem 23, due to J. Green, which justifies why elementary subgroups are important.

Comment: See my edit for an example with irreducible representations.

Comment: Your edit claims that the two irreducible reps of $D_{2\times 12}$ are the same after restriction to their Sylow subgroups. I showed it is false: Following Serre's chapter 5 notation, $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are distinguished by the order $8$ subgroup generated by $r^3$ and $s$. More specifically, the values of the characters at $r^3$ are $0$ and $-2$ resp.

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong character. There are two distinct characters whose restriction to $r^3$ is $0$. The character with restriction $-2$  is not faithful.

Comment: You are right! Following Serre's notation, the five irreps of degree $2$ are $\rho^1,...\rho^5$, among which only $\rho^1$ and $\rho^5$ are faithful. They are different for $D_{24}$ whose restrictions to the Sylow-$2$ and the Sylow-$3$ are all isomorphic!